# update menuconfig entries without recompiling all the kernel

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, openwrt, kbuild

I succesfully compiled the default linux distro for the Dragino Yun. It took me several hours.

I added a new .c file under `Dragino-Yun/openwrt/build_dir/linux-ar71xx_generic/linux-3.3.8/drivers/spi/` , the driver is `spi-gpio-custom.c`

I added this to drivers/spi/Kconfig:

```
config SPI_GPIO_CUSTOM
    tristate "Custom GPIO-based SPI driver"
    depends on GENERIC_GPIO
    select SPI_GPIO
    help
      This is an SPI driver to register 1 to 4 custom SPI buses using
      GPIO lines. Each bus can have up to 8 slaves.
      The devices will be exposed to userspace as /dev/spidevX.X
      
      This module is maily intended to interface microcontrollers
      and other SPI devices without a specific kernel driver.

      This support is also available as a module.  If so, the module
      will be called spi-gpio-custom.
```

And this to the Makefile:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_SPI_GPIO_CUSTOM)   += spi-gpio-custom.o
```

However, when I do: `make menuconfig` I cannot see this new entry.

I tried with: `make CONFIG_SPI_GPIO_CUSTOM=y`, but still I cannot see the entry with `make menuconfig`

How can I get to see the new entry in menuconfig without recompiling all the OS?

Comment: Configuration of the Linux kernel prepends its building, so `make menuconfig` does NOT require recompilation of the kernel. Probably, your entry is not seen because its clause `depends on` is not fulfilled by the current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with make kernel_menuconfig instead of make menuconfig

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).